# Синтаксис jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, синтаксис

Прошу прощения за такой нубский вопрос, но как сюда вставить переменную?

```
    var color
    $(this).removeClass().addClass(ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ_color);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var color = "black";
    $(this).removeClass(color).addClass(color);
```

Comment: Чушь какая-то, да еще и признанная, как лучший ответ... Не говорю уже о том, что не стыковка с вопросом, так еще и "переливание из пустого в порожнее". 

> Удаляем класс **black**, для того, чтобы сразу же его и добавить.

Comment: Вопрос вроде бы был - как использовать переменную в вызове функции а не как сделать это.
Мой пример показывает как функции 
removeClass()
и
addClass()

получают переменную

Comment: @Nord001, давайте не передёргивать. Цитата 

> как сюда вставить переменную

И указано место, куда надо "вставить" переменную

Comment: Хорошо - намекаете что это мой мульт? Или что?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/132335/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E

Этот вопрос вас не смущает?

Comment: @Nord001, мне намекать смысла нет, я бы прямо об этом высказал предположение. Кроме того, моего ответа тут нет и я не пытаюсь свой вопрос продвинуть. А выводит меня отсутствие логики в действиях ТС и вашем ответе.

Comment: Логику выбор правильного ответа ТС я не знаю, но я думаю потому что я был первым ответившим.


Это не мой мульт и на этом сайте у меня мультов нету - это не игра где они дял меня более-менее обоснованы, а сайт где я могу развеять скуку или найти интересую для себя вещь(временами такое находиться). 


И когда админы меня не удалят - я бы хотел что бы вы передо мной извинили за необоснованный наезд.

Comment: Необоснованный? Думаю, что в первом своем коментарии, я достаточно правильно всё обосновал. Поэтому извиняться не за что. А правильный ответ дал @oneboy, если это интересно.

Answer (score 4):

А может в вопросе имелось ввиду:

```
var peremennaya = 'kakoyeto_zhachenie';
$(this).removeClass('kakoyto_class').addClass(peremennaya+'_color');
```

Comment: да... жаль что мы не экстрасенсы...

Comment: А может хотелось что то типа 

    ...
    var variable = "lala";
    var lala_color = "tada";
    ...
    ....addClass(eval(variable+"_color))

?
:-)